# Variable Resistance

Tags: physics

I'm stuck on this question from a past paper.

A parachutist jumps out of a hot air balloon. The resistance is proportional to the speed of the parachutist. The parachutist has a terminal velocity of 4 ms<sup>-1</sup>

How far did he fall after 3 seconds.

I'm really not sure how to go about this question, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The downward acceleration  in the absence of resistance is g, and you are told there is an upward force proportional to speed.  So (letting primes be d/dt) z"=-g+kz' where k is the constant of proportionality between speed and resistance.  The terminal velocity lets you figure k, then you integrate the equation with respect to t.

Comment: Thanks, amazing what a little shove in the right direction can do.